# How to return JavaScript array to PHP script?

Tags: javascript, json, console, phantomjs

I am using `PhantomJS` to get a webpage title and url via PHP. My JavaScript function is

```
var page = require('webpage').create(), url;
url = phantom.args[0];

page.open(url, function (status) 
{
    var title = page.evaluate(function () 
    {
        return document.title;
    });

    var url = page.evaluate(function ()
    {
        return document.url;    
    });

    var results = new Array(2);
    results[0] = title;
    results[1] = url;
    console.info(results);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Then I try to echo the `results` array in my PHP that calls the function as JSON:

```
<?php
    header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    $url = $_GET['url'];
    $cmd = '/usr/local/bin/phantomjs pagetitle.js ' . $url;
    $results = exec($cmd);
    echo json_encode(array('pagetitle' => $results[0], 'url' => $results[1]));
?>
```

However I only get the first characters for `title` and `url` as output:

```
{"pagetitle":"T","url":"h"}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't help you on php (that's not my favorite language...) but the phantomjs script is invalid.

2 errors from my point of view :

- document.url is undefined => shoudl be document.URL (cas sensitive)
- output is not a JSON => call JSON.stringify

try this :

```
var page = require('webpage').create(), url;
url = phantom.args[0];

page.open(url, function (status) 
{
    var title = page.evaluate(function () 
    {
        return document.title;
    });

    var url = page.evaluate(function ()
    {
        return document.URL;    
    });

    var results = new Array(2);
    results[0] = title;
    results[1] = url;
    console.info(JSON.stringify(results));
    phantom.exit();
});
```